Using Graph to create a calendar, no errors but nothing happens?
I am using MS Graph to create an event in a users calendar. I have written the following code and it runs without an error but nothing gets posted. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code or how to get feedback on what is happening?
I have been beating my head against the wall for 2 days.
I have checked and the all the azure settings and api permissions are set correctly. Here is the code that i have so far.
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using static System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter;

namespace PopulateCalendar
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();


            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential
                (
                config["GraphCalendar:TenantId"],
                config["GraphCalendar:ClientId"],
                config["GraphCalendar:ClientSecret"],
                new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud }
                );

            string OrganizerEmail = "purchasing@cantonfoodco.com";

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

            var requestBody = new Event
            {
                Subject = "Event Subject",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "What the event is about",
                },
                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2024-11-29T10:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
                },
                End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2024-11-29T14:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
                },
                Location = new Location
                {
                    DisplayName = "Location of Event",
                },

                TransactionId = "7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A7",
            };


            // To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=csharp
            var calendars = graphServiceClient.Users[config["GraphCalendar:UserObjectId"]]
                .Calendars["AQMkAGEzZDM0OTY5LWMzMjgtNGIxMy05ZWQ4LWM0MzZmYjY3NwA0YzUARgAAA4FoDJtpplFKsFjbsbk87SMHAPRwDiDSU_BCkOt4FQfkqmQAAAIBBgAAAPRwDiDSU_BCkOt4FQfkqmQAAAITCgAAAA=="]
                .Events
                .PostAsync(requestBody);
        }
    }
}


I have tried different mailboxes, recreated a new mailbox with no changes.

Your are calling asynchronous method PostAsync, but you don't wait until the request is sent and processed by the Graph API. The app ends before the request is sent.
Implement async/await pattern. static async Task and await graphServiceClient.... Also add try/catch block
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();


        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential
            (
            config["GraphCalendar:TenantId"],
            config["GraphCalendar:ClientId"],
            config["GraphCalendar:ClientSecret"],
            new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud }
            );

        string OrganizerEmail = "purchasing@cantonfoodco.com";

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

        var requestBody = new Event
        {
            Subject = "Event Subject",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = "What the event is about",
            },
            Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = "2024-11-29T10:00:00",
                TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
            },
            End = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = "2024-11-29T14:00:00",
                TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
            },
            Location = new Location
            {
                DisplayName = "Location of Event",
            },

            TransactionId = "7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A7",
        };


        // To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=csharp
        try
        {
            var newEvent = await graphServiceClient.Users[config["GraphCalendar:UserObjectId"]]
            .Calendars["AQMkAGEzZDM0OTY5LWMzMjgtNGIxMy05ZWQ4LWM0MzZmYjY3NwA0YzUARgAAA4FoDJtpplFKsFjbsbk87SMHAPRwDiDSU_BCkOt4FQfkqmQAAAIBBgAAAPRwDiDSU_BCkOt4FQfkqmQAAAITCgAAAA=="]
            .Events
            .PostAsync(requestBody);
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error?.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error?.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}


Thank you so much, can't believe i didn't realize that. Works perfectly now.
